# Ajax post error but errorThrown empty

Tags: php, ajax, post

Can someone help me in find what's my error in tihis ajax post request?

This is html

```
<select onchange="fetch_pro(this.value);">
    <option>select</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</ option>
    <option value="2">option 2</ option>
    <option value="3">option 3</ option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>       

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function fetch_pro(val)
        { 
         $.ajax({
         type: 'post',
         url: 'fetch.php',
         data: {
          id_reg:val
         },
         dataType: "json", 
         cache: false,
         success: function (response) {
          alert (response); 
         },
         error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
            alert("Status: " + textStatus); alert("Error: " + errorThrown);
        } , 
         });
        }   
</script>
```

and this is sample fetch.php

```
<?php
echo "ok";
?>
```

It return status error but error empty, what's wrong?

Comment: contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",

Comment: data: JSON.stringify({ id_reg:val })

Comment: can you try echo json_encode(array('status' => 'success')); in the php file and check

Comment: it seem that the php was not reached...

Comment: Deep nothing! not working with content-type and modify of data...